# How can I find out what user Hudson is running under

Tags: hudson

I've taken over handling Hudson from a contractor and I'm wanting to know what user the hudson is running under.

I need this because I've made a new job which will sync a folder with another folder on a mapped drive. This mapped drive is only available to the build user (user as in what you log into windows with, not log into hudson).

The job itself is getting a 'Failed to copy' error in the log which I believe is because i'm using the wrong windows user and there is no mapped drive? Or would this cause another error?

Regards

Comment: I'm on windows server. I have opened task manager but i don't see a Hudson process. When I run a build the processes that are using the cpu is Java.exe (I wasn't running the build before and nothing showed, which is why I asked the question)
. So I would assume that would be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out what web server or servlet container (such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org)) Hudson is deployed on. Hudson is a web application and will use the same user as the web server it is deployed on.

Comment: Thanks this is it. There was no hudson.exe.

Answer (score 4):

If linux:

```
ps -ef | grep hudson
```

The owner of the process will be shown (along with other info).

Comment: Thanks, though I'm on windows. I will clarify a bit more under my question

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to do this from within Hudson by going to Manage Hudson > Script Console and adding the following.

```
println(System.getProperty("user.name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It obviously runs as a service, so check what services are defined and what user they run as.

You can also use the task manager and check the "Show processes from all users". There should be a Hudson.exe, check what username it is running under.

I just found out about tasklist and taskkill. So you can also run the following command:

`tasklist /fi  "IMAGENAME eq hudson.exe"`

Comment: Hudson is a web application, not a standalone executable.

Comment: @Bernhard: There are several options to run Hudson. We use the build in winstone engine and installed it as a service. You will than see the Hudson.exe in the task manager. It can also be deployed to an application server, in that case I would suspect that the application will run in the user context of the application server. Without getting more information on this, we can only guess a solution to help Lango.